# spike in dns queries

Tags: domain-name-system, host

I have an app hosted on Heroku and I use Zerigo DNS. In Zerigo's statistics page I see that over the course of a month the DNS queries are on average 1500/day. Then, all of a sudden over the last week they spiked up to 115,000 in a day for a few days.

I can't find any information regarding this. Is this a DNS attack? Should I be worried?

Comment: Did your hits go up?

Answer (score 0):

A mere 115k DNS queries in a day does not constitute an "attack".

If the extra DNS traffic doesn't affect your bill then don't worry about it.

Comment: where is it came from ?